# How to determine what to set deviation to

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

[image]

I have a function that’s sets a deviation percentage to each players fantasy points per game. For example, if I set deviation to 50% a player with a projected score of 10 will be given a floor of 5 points and a ceiling of 15 points then the function will randomly choose a number between the floor and ceiling. However, every slate has a different number of players and therefore a different number of quality players (quality meaning players who aren’t super risky). How could I determine what to set the variance parameter to given a certain amount of players to choose from? Could I use the population average standard deviation - meaning take every player’s std then average all of them? Or is there a different approach that would work better for this particular problem?

Comment: Your question is quite vague at the moment. How about you post an example of what the scores of each player are?

Comment: @TobyMak Shane Bieber would have a random number generated between 18.25 and 54.75. My question is on nights when you have more players to choose from wouldn't you want a higher deviation and when you have less players to choose from a lower deviation?